# I can return the full array, but not the array slice

Tags: angular

I'm creating a basic blog with Angular and Cockpit CMS. I successfully pulled the blog entries from Cockpit into an array. When I return the array in its entirety, it works. If I try to return a slice, I get nothing.

Posts Service:

```
  export class PostsService {

  private posts: Post[] = [];
  private postsUrl = 'collections/get/Posts';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  FetchPosts() {
    let tempArray: Post[] = [];
    this.http
        .get(environment.baseurl + this.postsUrl + environment.vpitKey)
        .subscribe(
            res => {
              tempArray.push(res);
            },
            error => {
              console.log('error receiving data...');
            },
            () => {
              for (let entry of tempArray[0]['entries']) {
                this.posts.push(entry);
              }
              this.posts.reverse();
            }
        );
  }

  getFirstPost() {
    return this.posts.slice(0, 1);

  }

  getAddlPosts() {
    return this.posts.slice(1);
  }

}
```

Component.ts:

```
  firstPost: Post[];
  addlPosts: Post[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private postService: PostsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.postService.FetchPosts();
    this.firstPost = this.postService.getFirstPost();
    this.addlPosts = this.postService.getAddlPosts();
  }
```

Both firstPost and addlPosts are empty arrays.  If I change the service to `return this.posts`, then the entire array is returned successfully.

Comment: this is **asynchronous**, `this.postService.FetchPosts()` is not finished before the next two lines is executed, thus empty arrays are returned.

Comment: But if I change the `getFirstPost()` to `return this.posts;` it returns the full array.

Comment: @AJT_82 you are correct, the service should return observable of posts instead of pretending to be synchronious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since angular execution is asynchronous and will not wait for statement complete its execution when there is http call.

Since in fetchPosts() you are making API call it will not wait, SO it will continue executing the further lines i.e before the it gets the posts it will execute

```
this.firstPost = this.postService.getFirstPost();
this.addlPosts = this.postService.getAddlPosts();
```

the above two lines where currently posts array is empty in postService.

**You need to use callback like below**

In Postservice.ts

```
FetchPosts(cb) {
let tempArray: Post[] = [];
this.http
    .get(environment.baseurl + this.postsUrl + environment.vpitKey)
    .subscribe(
        res => {
          tempArray.push(res);
        },
        error => {
          console.log('error receiving data...');
          cb(null, null)
        },
        () => {
          for (let entry of tempArray[0]['entries']) {
            this.posts.push(entry);
          }
          this.posts.reverse();
          cb(this.posts.slice(0, 1), this.posts.slice(1))
        }
    );
```

}

in component.ts will be like

```
ngOnInit() {
this.postService.FetchPosts((firstPost, addlPosts)=>{
  this.firstPost = firstPost;
  this.addlPosts = addlPosts;
 });
```

}

**Angular way of doing**

In postservice.ts file

```
async FetchPosts() {
let tempArray: Post[] = [];
try{
let response = await this.http
    .get(environment.baseurl + this.postsUrl + environment.vpitKey).toPromise()
this.posts = response.[0]['entries'].map(_=>_)
this.posts.reverse()
} catch(err){
  console.log('error receiving data...');
}
```

}

In Component.ts file add code below

```
async ngOnInit() {
    await this.postService.FetchPosts();
    this.firstPost = this.postService.getFirstPost();
    this.addlPosts = this.postService.getAddlPosts();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth response. This made sense to me, and worked perfectly!

Comment: if it works, Please upvote to my answer @CareyHead, thanx

Comment: @ajaykumarmp Even though your solution is a valid one, a better approach might be using **Promises** or **Observables** for a more up to date answer and an Angular way of doing this.

Comment: @DavidFontes i have edited code to match with up to date which is angular way of doing. Now?